# python class if value == 'ALL' get all value

Tags: python, class, pandas

I'm a newbie to use the class. I encounter a problem when I use the class. the code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class Weather(object):
    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._url

    @url.setter
    def url(self, value):
        if value == 'GZ' or value == 'ZH' or value == 'ALL':
            self._url = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('parameter Error')

    def print_df(self):
        df_em = pd.DataFrame()
        df = pd.DataFrame({'k1': [1, 2, 3],
                       'k2': [2, 3, 4]})
        for self._url in ['GZ', 'ZH']:
            df['val'] = self._url
            df_em = df_em.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        if self._url == 'ALL':
           print df_em
        else:
            print df_em[df_em.val == self._url]

s = Weather()
s.url = 'ZH'
s.print_df()
```

the result I got when I change the attribute  `s.url == 'GZ'` or  `s.url == 'ALL'`:

```
     k1  k2 val
 0   1   2  ZH
 1   2   3  ZH
 2   3   4  ZH
```

the result I wanted to get:

```
s.url = 'ZH'
s.print_df()

       k1  k2 val
   0   1   2  ZH
   1   2   3  ZH
   2   3   4  ZH

s.url = 'GZ'
s.print_df()

       k1  k2 val
   0   1   2  GZ
   1   2   3  GZ
   2   3   4  GZ

s.url = 'ALL'
s.print_df()

       k1  k2 val
   0   1   2  GZ
   1   2   3  GZ
   2   3   4  GZ
   3   1   2  ZH
   4   2   3  ZH
   5   3   4  ZH
```

I don't know where the error occur. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way to fix your code is to replace:

```
for self._url in ['GZ', 'ZH']:
    df['val'] = self._url
```

with

```
for url in ['GZ', 'ZH']:
    df['val'] = url
```

Then it works.

It didn't work, because you are changing your protected attribute `self._url`, which should contain the url you want to display.

### Some improvement

Moreover, you are constructing the DataFrame in the printing part, which is not, I would say, elegant. I would go with class someting like this:

```
import pandas as pd


class Weather(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Attribute initialization
        self.df_em = self._construct_df()

        # Constant initialization
        self._url = None

    def _construct_df(self):
        df_em = pd.DataFrame()
        df = pd.DataFrame({'k1': [1, 2, 3],
                           'k2': [2, 3, 4]})
        for url in ['GZ', 'ZH']:
            df['val'] = url
            df_em = df_em.append(df, ignore_index=True)

        return df_em

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._url

    @url.setter
    def url(self, value):
        if value in ['GZ', 'ZH', 'ALL']:
            self._url = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('parameter Error')

    def print_df(self):
        if self.url == 'ALL':
            print self.df_em
        else:
            print self.df_em[self.df_em.val == self.url]
```

which has divided the construction and display part.